# NGINX subdomain and proxy_pass for Mumble

Tags: ssl, nginx, proxy, subdomain

I currently have a NGINX configuration with many subdomains. I started a `mumble-server` on port `27845`, it works if I try to access it on a Mumble client with `<ip_adress>:27845`.

I tried to use NGINX to provide a subdomain `mumble.example.com` on port `80`, which use `proxy_pass http://localhost:27845`. But when I try to connect to `mumble.example.com` on my Mumble client, it says that :

`This server is using an older encryption standard, and is no longer supported by modern versions of Mumble.`

How can I use a valid SSL configuration for NGINX on the port `80` ? I can use solely ports `80` and `443`, and `443` is used for OpenVPN.

Subdomain conf NGINX :

```
server {
  server_name mumble.example.com;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:27845;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nginx is an HTTP proxy, but mumble protocol is based on TCP/UDP, so I don't think Nginx can proxy for murmur service.

Comment: Oh, didn't even think about the protocol .. I'll try to look with plain TCP with nginx, thanks !

Comment: Nginx has supported UDP load balancing since 2016.